# unable to upload multiple image in cake php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a form and trying to upload multiple image .All thing right with single image . when I am trying to upload multiple  image,Then  I receive only one image in output .
Here is my View file.

```
<div class="from-control-div">
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Post', array('type' => 'file','id'=>'unitform','class'=>'form-horizontal','role'=>'form','url' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'savepost')));?>
<div class="from-div-bottom">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">File Upload</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="more-files">
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('files.',array('type'=>'file','label' => false,'placeholder' => 'Upload images','id'=>"inputFile",'multiple','onchange'=>'readURL(this)'));?>
            <!--<div id="fileList"></div>-->
        </div>
        <a class="col-sm-2 pull-right" style="font-weight:bold;" id="add-more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>  
  </form>
```

After this here is my controller.If I print      print_r($data); then output is single array. No multiple array receive .Any help for me

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => download.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpX3Oy32 [error] => 0 [size] => 12988 ) )



      public function savepost() {
        if (count($this->request->data) > 0) {
      $fileNames = '';
            if (isset($this->request->data['Post']['files']) && count($this->request->data['Post']['files']) > 0) {
              $data=$this->request->data['Post']['files'];
                print_r($data);
             $fileNames = array();
                foreach ($this->request->data['Post']['files'] as $filedata) {
          if(isset($filedata["name"]) && ($filedata["name"] !='')){
            $upload_dir = FILE_UPLOAD_PATH;
            $original = explode('.', $filedata["name"]);
            $extension = array_pop($original);
            $newname = time() . '.' . $extension;
            if (file_exists($upload_dir . $newname)) {
              unlink($upload_dir . $newname);
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($filedata["tmp_name"], $upload_dir . $newname)) {
              $fileNames[] = $newname;
                        print_r($fileNames);
            }
          }
                }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public function savepost() {

```
if(isset($this->request->data['multifiles'])){
    $file_name_all="";
    for($i=0; $i<count($this->request->data['multifiles']); $i++){
        if(!empty($this->request->data['multifiles'][$i]['name'])){
            $file = $this->request->data['multifiles'][$i];
            $file['name'] =  time() . '-' . str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']); 
            $uploadPath = WWW_ROOT . 'img/ ';
            $fileName =  $file['name'];
            $uploadFile = $uploadPath.$fileName;
            $file_name_all.= $file['name'].",";
            if($file['name']){
                move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadFile);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

}

in my code it is working.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to arbitrary file uploads! An attacker can upload any file, to possibly arbitrary locations, imagine for example `$file['name']` would contain `exploit.php`, you don't want people to be able to upload that to your server! Make sure that you always validate and sanitize user input, at the very least validate the extension and pass the name through `basename()`!